# Get complete value out of excel cell with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Upon opening the xls sheet, I see a value of "13.09". If I click on that cell, I can see a value of "13.087100872". I need to extract the unrounded value for all cells without manually opening the excel file.

I have tried

```
cell.getNumericCellValue()
```

as well as

```
objectDefaultFormat.formatCellValue(cell, objFormulaEvaluator)
```

where objDefaultFormat is a DataFormatter and objFormulaEvaluator is a FormulaEvaluator:

```
DataFormatter objDefaultFormat = new DataFormatter();
FormulaEvaluator objFormulaEvaluator = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator((HSSFWorkbook) wb);
```

What do I need to do differently to get the unrounded value?

Comment: As far as I can see, `cell.getNumericCellValue()` is the right solution. So what did that return, and why is that not what you want?

Comment: It seems that does work. I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the help.